# YAML ERROR : mapping values are not allowed

Tags: yaml

I am trying to build a yaml file but I am getting mapping not allowed error.

```
name: n1
version: "testv1"
description: n1
icon: n1.png
roles: [postgres]
postgres:
   name: postgreSQL database
   image:
       name: "r/k/postgres/"
       version: "testv1"
       engine: docker
   compute:
       memory: 2G
       cpu:
           reserve: false
           cores: 2
   storage:
       - type: data1
         media: hdd
         path: /var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
         size: 30G
         count: 1
         fixed: true
   service_ports: [5432]
   env:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD:
            type: password
            value: "postgres"
      POSTGRES_DB: postgres
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
```

(): mapping values are not allowed in this context at line 21 column 14

I cant understand the error on line :  size: 30G

Answer (score 0):

Try adding double quotes to the following:

```
path: "/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata"
```

Also, *indentation of keys in the map should be exactly same*. Try seeing that the indentation is correct. So, for example, if you are using 3 spaces to indent a key, then every key should be indented with 3 spaces only.